# How to retrieve image details from the array on click over the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, list

I have been working on a code for image tagging, where I save the tags of the image in a database.
So what I did in the code is, the user who is logged in the system will first draw a box over the image for tagging. and then click confirm. onclick the confirm button, the bounding box location along with the image name is stored in a database. you see the image of the tag screen in image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JgHm.png).

Along with the storing the values in the database , I also push these tag location value into an array. What i wanted to do is to get the values again from the array list when again clicked on the image.

Below is the code I used to post the values using ajax:

```
  $('.confirm').click(function(){
        var areas = $('img#img01').selectAreas('areas');
        displayAreas(areas);

        var imgarray=[];

        var x_value= document.getElementById('x').value;
        var y_value= document.getElementById('y').value;
        var w_value= document.getElementById('w').value;
        var h_value= document.getElementById('h').value;
        var fullPath = document.getElementById("img01").src;
        var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
  

        document.getElementById("result").value = filename;

        var img_name= document.getElementById('result').value;
       
  imgarray.push({"img_name":img_name.value,"x":x_value.value,"y":y_value.value,"w":w_value.value,"h":h_value.value});

        $.ajax({
                          type:'POST',
                          url: 'sendfile.php',
                          data:{
                            'x_value': x_value,
                            'y_value': y_value,
                            'w_value': w_value,
                            'h_value': h_value,
                            'img_name':img_name,
                            'imagecount':imagecount,
                          },
                          success: function(data){
                            alert("success");
                            console.log(img_name);
                          }


      });
              
      });
```

Image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JgHm.png):

[image]

the above image shows the tag screen , where the user clicks confirm to store the tag details.

Image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04OPM.png) shows the screen where the images are displayed which on click should display the details of the image and tag.[expected output].

Image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04OPM.png):

[image]

I used the code below to push the tag details in to the array:

```
      imgarray.push({"img_name":img_name.value,"x":x_value.value,"y":y_value.value,"w":w_value.value,"h":h_value.value});
```

The expected output is when I click the image again after tagging , it should alert the tag details that where stored in the array.
I tried like this :

```
 alert("img_array"+img_array[0].img_name);
```

but it displayed the alert undefined. Can someone help me resolve this problem and help me to print all the tag details on the alert message.

Comment: using alert is a horrible debugging tool. Try `console.log(img_array[0])` and see what that looks like in dev tools console

Comment: @charlietfl i tried it , still gives me the output as undefined

Comment: @charlietfl same result, undefined

Comment: Ohhh... this is a typo. Code in question  is using `imgarray` not `img_array`

Comment: no .. i tried with imgarray @charlietfl

Comment: Sounds like a scope problem. Not showing where `imgarray` is defined vs where you are triyng to use it in the click event. Is defined inside another function perhaps? Or multiple document.ready calls?

Comment: @charlietfl u can see the code , i have defined imgarray inside the button function

Comment: Oh yeah...then you need to define it outside so you can access it again and don't create a new instance every click of  confirm

Comment: @charlietfl can u show me what to change, i got confused little

Comment: Instead of `$('.confirm').click(function(){ ... var imgarray =[]...`    do  `var imgarray =[]; $('.confirm').click..`. Then it is accessible in other event handlers also

Comment: @charlietfl I found a solution , I changed the values in the i            imgarray.push({"img_name":img_name,"x":x_value,"y":y_value,"w":w_value,"h":h_value});
now its working